# Loss of information when finding gcd of large numbers?

Tags: python, cryptography, numbers, rsa

Currently creating an RSA script and after finding the totient of a large number n (which is equal to 2161435923146879872768) and running the gcd algorithm on it, I always get back 5.0 instead of the expected 1.0 so I can run the rest of my program.

```
def gcd(a, b):
    # Return GCD using Euclid's Algo.
    while a != 0:
        a, b = b % a, a
    return b


def modinv(a, m):
    # Returns modular inverse of a % m
    if gcd(a, m) != 1:
        return None
    u1, u2, u3 = 1, 0, a
    v1, v2, v3 = 0, 1, m
    while v3 != 0:
        q = u3 // v3
        v1, v2, v3, u1, u2, u3 = (u1 - q * v1), (u2 - q * v2), (u3 - q * v3), v1, v2, v3
    return u1 % m

# p = 43603303097 and q = 49570463009
# e = 45445
totient_n = (p - 1) * (q - 1)
d = modinv(e, totient_n)
```

Every time p-1 and q-1 are multiplied the value is computed incorrectly or rounded improperly (2161435923146879795200L or 2.1614359231468798e+21). How do I avoid this and get the correct gcd of 1?

Comment: Forgot to note that e = 45445 for this problem

Comment: you should add that information to the question, not in a comment.

Comment: I get gcd(e, totient_n) = 1, are you sure that you didn't make p, q or e non-integer somewhere?

Comment: put "assert type(a) is int and type(b) is int" inside gcd function

Comment: Voting to close, since this is a spurious problem caused by the inappropriate use of floating-point input variables where integer variables were required.